# how to validate dynamic text boxes using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i need to validate dynamically created text boxes,here i created three text boxes then map function is validate all the three text boxes,but if validation is false that time also page is submitted.what i want is if validation is false stop the submit.help me...

//email.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Settings</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js">             </script>
    <style>
     p {
        font-size:12px;
        color:red;
      }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#submit').click(function(e){
       i = 0;
       $('input[name="email[]"]').map(function(){
       console.log(i++);
       email = $(this).val();
       console.log(email);

       if(validateEmail(email) === false )
        {
          alert('Invalid email-id');
          //$('#p2').html("Please Enter a Email-id");
          return false;
        }
      return false;
     });

    });
   });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateEmail(email) { 
           var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return re.test(email);
         }
         </script>
         </head>
         <body>
           <form name="form" id="fakkir" action="#" method="post">
             <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email1"/></br>
             <p id="p2"></p>
             <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email2"/></br>
             <p id="p3"></p>
             <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email3" /></br>
             <p id="p4"></p>

             <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is edited js script. Put your `validateEmail` inside `ready` function. I have used `submit` event.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fakkir').on("submit",function(e){
   //$('input[name="email[]"]').each(function(){
    //$('input[name="email[]"]').click(function() {
     i = 0;
       var isValid = true;
     $('input[name="email[]"]').map(function(){
     console.log(i++);
     email = $(this).val();
      console.log(email);
     //alert($(this).val());

     if(validateEmail(email) === false )
      {
          isValid = false;
        alert('Invalid email-id');
          //$('#p2').html("Please Enter a Email-id");
          return false;
       }
      return false;
     });
       if(isValid){          
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }

       });
    function validateEmail(email) { 
           var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return re.test(email);
         }
     });
```

Here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdghzgkn/)

Comment: hai karan thanks,,,,but still form is submitted....i need if user enter invalid or empty email id...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

before return false.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Settings</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
 p {
  font-size:12px;
        color:red;
      }
 </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(e){
   //$('input[name="email[]"]').each(function(){
    //$('input[name="email[]"]').click(function() {
     i = 0;
     $('input[name="email[]"]').map(function(){
     console.log(i++);
     email = $(this).val();
      console.log(email);
     //alert($(this).val());

     if(validateEmail(email) === false )
      {
        alert('Invalid email-id');
          //$('#p2').html("Please Enter a Email-id");
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
       }
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
     });
      /*
          i = 0;
         $('input[name="email[]"]').each(function(){ 
          console.log(i++);
           console.log('welcome');
           email = $('input[name="email[]"]').val();
             console.log(email);
             alert($(this).val());
             /*var reg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

                if(email==""){
                $('#p2').html("Please Enter a Email-id");
                $('input[name="email[]"]').focus();

                return false;
                }
            else if(!email.match(reg)){
                $('#p2').html("Please Enter a Valid Email-id");
                $('input[name="email[]"]').focus();
                return false;
                }*/
          //});*/
      //});
      });
     });
  </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    /*function validate(email){
    var reg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
     if(email==""){
          return false;
         }
       else if(!email.match(reg)){
                return false;
                }else{
                return true;
                }
         }*/

           function validateEmail(email) { 
           var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return re.test(email);
         }
           </script>
         </head>
             <body>
           <form name="form" id="fakkir" action="#" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email1"/></br>
           <p id="p2"></p>
            <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email2"/></br>
         <p id="p3"></p>
        <input type="text" name="email[]" id="email3" /></br>
       <p id="p4"></p>

         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
          </form>
             </body>
             </html>
```

Comment: No. Its works form me. Can you check these fiddles
With my code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1a5v-779z
With your code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1a5v-779z -  here you can see the website is reloading as a result of submit.

Comment: when i load that page it look this http://localhost/amit/email.html but after submitting it chage into http://localhost/amit/email.html#...because it is submitting

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit').on('click',function(e){

     i = 0;
         var v = 0;
     $('input[name="email[]"]').map(function(){

     email = $(this).val();


     if(validateEmail(email) === false )
      {
          v=1;
        alert('Invalid email-id');
          e.preventDefault();

       }

     });
         console.log(v);
         if (v == 0) {
             alert('valid')
            $('#fakkir').submit();
       }
      });
     });
        function validateEmail(email) { 
           var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return re.test(email);
         }
     </script>
```